# How to I access a view in a view controllers extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm getting an error for self.view saying 'UIViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'view'

```
extension UIViewController {

    class func addBackgroundImage() {
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView();
        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "splashBackground");
        backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView);
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        backgroundImageView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(insets)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `addBackgroundImage` as a `class func`. This means `self` will be the class object, not an instance of the class.

Use `func addBackgroundImage() { ... }` instead.